Perfect Reconstruction Condition of DWT
According to several publications, e.g, https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4614-1821-4_6#Sec5, the following conditions ensure perfect reconstruction of a DWT:

alias cancellation:

distortionless:


Here, H are low-pass and G are high-pass filters. A tilde denotes the reconstruction filters.
I have implemented that in python and checked it with all discrete wavelets from pywt:
import pywt
import numpy as np

for w in pywt.wavelist(kind="discrete"):
    dec_lo, dec_hi, rec_lo, rec_hi = map(np.array, pywt.Wavelet(w).filter_bank)
    alias_cancellation = np.sum(rec_lo * dec_lo[::-1]) + np.sum(rec_hi * dec_hi[::-1]) # should be 0
    distortionless = np.sum(rec_lo * dec_lo) + np.sum(rec_hi * dec_hi) # should be 2
    print(w, alias_cancellation, distortionless) # returns (w, 2, 0) but should be (w, 0, 2) for all wavelets

In contrast to the definitions from the paper, my python script returns 2 for alias_cancellation and 0 for distortionless, but it should be 0 and 2, respectively. What am I missing here?

I don't think you need to do the [::-1] yourself: the filters have already been reversed.
